# Deploy Azure Bot error "Updates to converged applications are not allowed in this version."

Tags: azure, botframework, azure-keyvault, azure-bot-service

I want to deploy my bot using this instruction https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/bot-builder-tutorial-deploy-basic-bot?view=azure-bot-service-4.0&tabs = csharp, but on the third point I have a problem.
I am running the command "az ad app create --display-name" displayName "--password" AtLeastSixteenCharacters_0 "--available-to-other-tenants".
In place of "displayName" I insert the name of the bot, and on "AtLeastSixteenCharacters_0" I enter a random password, but I get the answer "Found an existing application instance of" ******************** ** ". We will patch it
Updates to converged applications are not allowed in this version ".
If the password field is left blank, the operation will be successful, but how can I get this password?
In the Azure portal, on the bot tab in the Configuration section, the Microsoft App ID (Manage) field displays the id and the tooltip says that "You can generate a new password by clicking on the 'Manage' link." is a No access 403 error.
How can I get this password

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Solution 1:** An Azure Bot resource has an **application ID (app ID)** and a **password** associated with it. The Azure Bot Service assigns a unique application ID to the application. You can obtain the password following the steps described below.

**1)** In your browser, navigate to the [Azure portal](https://ms.portal.azure.com/).

**2)** In the resource list, click on the registration application name.

**3)** In the right panel go to the Bot Management section and click **Settings**. The registration application Settings page will display.

**4)** Select the **Manage** link next to Microsoft App ID.

[image]

**5)** In the **Certificates & secrets** pane, click the **New client secret** button.

[image]

**6)** Add the description, select the expiration time, and click the **Add** button.
[image]

This will generate a new password for your bot. Copy this password and save it to a file. This is the only time you will see this password. If you do not have the full password saved, you will need to repeat the process to create a new password should you need it later.

For more details refer this [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/bot-service-manage-settings?view=azure-bot-service-4.0)

**Solution 2:**  Use the latest version of the Azure CLI. If you are using an Azure CLI version older than 2.2.0, you might encounter errors.

**1)**  Login to azure portal

```
az login
```

**Note:** If you deploy your bot to a non-Azure cloud such as US Gov, you need to run az cloud set --name  before az login, where  is the name of a registered cloud, such as AzureUSGovernment. If you want to go back to public cloud, you can run az cloud set --name AzureCloud.

**2)**  Set the default subscription to use.

```
az account set --subscription "<azure-subscription-id>"
```

**3)** create an Azure application registration

```
az ad app create --display-name "displayName" --password "AtLeastSixteenCharacters_0" --available-to-other-tenants
```

**display-name**    :The display name of the application. It is listed in the Azure portal in the general resources list and in the resource group it belongs.

**Password** :The password, also known as client secret, for the application. This is a password you create for this resource. It must be at least 16 characters long, contain at least 1 upper or lower case alphabetical character, and contain at least 1 special character.

**available-to-other-tenants** :    Indicates that the application can be used from any Azure AD tenant. Set this to enable your bot to work with the Azure Bot Service channels

For more details refer this [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/bot-builder-deploy-az-cli?view=azure-bot-service-4.0&tabs=csharp#create-the-azure-application-registration).